# Unable to invoke Chrome browser version greater than 34 with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

selenium standalone server version 2.47.1

Google Chrome driver version - 2.21

Unable to invoke Chrome browser of version greater than 34 with Selenium Web driver.

Can anyone help me how to resolve this.

Comment: When you say unable to invoke chrome browser, what do you mean ? Do you have any logs etc., that can add more details to your problem ?
Here's some stuff that you can do on your own and post back on your findings :
ChromeDriver version : Run the command "chromedriver --version" and share output.

Comment: Here's some stuff that you can do on your own and post back on your findings :
ChromeDriver version : Run "chromedriver --version" and share output.
Spawn chrome manually:
1. Start chromedriver: "chromedriver --verbose" 
2. Now try triggering a POST to the end-point : http://localhost:9515/session [ use port number from (1)]
Payload :
{ "desiredCapabilities":{ "browserName":"chrome"}}
You should see browser spawn. Share logs shown on console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloaded and replaced latest chromedriver.exe and the issue got solved.

Thanks Krishnan Mahadevan.